# network mounted drives on Windows 10 are only "read only"

Tags: windows-10, permissions, mount

I am trying to add a drive on my laptop, which is shared from another computer on the network.

If I open the drive from the network folder, I can access it in read and write no problem. 
Then I tried to mount it as "network mounted" on Windows 10, so I can have it mounted automatically when I boot the laptop, but it is not writable.

I tried to change permissions but I get an error, like if I was not the owner of the folder; although both the laptop and the desktop are using the same Microsoft account for the login.

Are network mounted drives always set as read only for security reasons, or can it be changed?

Comment: How do you open the drive from the network folder exactly, and what options are you selecting, etc. when you map the drive. Did you simple try `NET USE X: \\server\share` like that with no credential? If you can access via straight `\\servername\sharename` and press enter and it opens with read and write but after you map it you have different read-only access, then this sounds like you are mapping it to use a different security context than the account you are logged onto the machine with when it does work or whatever. Disclose more detail please of your process exactly.

Comment: If you are mounting with Linux just to test, use a syntax in a similar format such as: `mount -t cifs //<IPAddress>/<ShareName> -o username=<username>,password=<password> /mnt/<ShareName>` by putting in the explicit credential that way that you are using when it allows you the read and write access.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints! I was indeed using the command without passing the correct permission. I did remove the mount point, and set permission to read/write for anyone and it is working now. I was thinking that Windows could override the sharing settings, but I was quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pimp Juice IT I did figure out that the permissions where wrong to start with.

Windows create all the shares as read only, except for the system user. When mounting, since your user is XXXX and not system, the permissions is in read only (make sense in a corporate world to have read only by default,unless you are the admin).

I did stop the sharing, share it again and then in the settings I did enable R/W for every user. It is not safe, I know, but it is a home network so if they can get to one computer, they can get also on the other that has the drive in it, so the concern is limited.

Thanks again for showing me where the problem was!